# upload many images from android Sd to PHp in samsung is9023

Tags: android

iused：

```
private void postFile() {

    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    httpclient.getParams().setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.PROTOCOL_VERSION, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);

    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(ConstValue.SEARCH_BY_PICTER);

    File file = new File(currentPath);

    ContentBody cbFile = new FileBody(file, "image/jpeg");
    MultipartEntity mpEntity = new MultipartEntity();

    try {
        mpEntity.addPart("fileToUpload", cbFile);
        mpEntity.addPart("sys", new StringBody("android"));
        mpEntity.addPart("ver", new StringBody(ConstValue.VERSION_NAME));
        mpEntity.addPart("cid", new StringBody(cid));
        mpEntity.addPart("page", new StringBody("1"));
        mpEntity.addPart("offset", new StringBody("80"));
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e2.printStackTrace();
    }

    httppost.setEntity(mpEntity);

    // System.out.println("executing request " + httppost.getRequestLine());
    HttpResponse response = null;
    try {
        response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();


    // System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());
    if (resEntity != null) {
        try {
            final String response_str = EntityUtils.toString(resEntity);
            if (!response_str.contains("@@@@")) {
                ConstValue.goodByPiclist = GoodXMLUtil.parseResponse(response_str);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(context, "sorry,server is busy", 2000).show();
            }

            // Log.d("log", response_str);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    if (resEntity != null) {
        try {
            resEntity.consumeContent();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
}
```

i used jar is httpmime-4.1.2.jar,the code is very well in android and other phone.but in samsung is9023 not run,if my code have mistake,if yes can you give me some advice or some good other method.very  very thank you

edit: sorry i have solved the problem ,my code is right,and samsung is good,my mistake is i put image size is not valid

edit：i have meet new problem,in samsung  only upload Pure color succeed as Pure white,Pure Black.other htc android phone any color ie very well.if samsung  is9023 not trust httpmime-4.1.2.jar very well.because in php not receive any data if i used other pic in samsung

Comment: "but in samsung is9023 not run," -  What's d problem? Have you get any error?

Answer (score 0):

one possibilty can be that `currentPath` is hard coded like ../sdcard/ and as every device have diffrent external storage location so use `Environment.getExternalDirectory()` instead .